# How to calculate Land Surface Emissivity using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am trying to calculate Land Surface Emissivity using QGIS

When the NDVI is less than 0, it is classified as water, and the emissivity value of 0.991 is assigned. For NDVI values between 0 and 0.2, it is considered that the land is covered with soil, and the emissivity value of 0.996 is assigned. Values between 0.2 and 0.5 are considered mixtures of soil and vegetation cover and (6) is applied to retrieve the emissivity. In the last case, when the NDVI value is greater than 0.5, it is considered to be covered with vegetation, and the value of 0.973 is assigned.

_{V}*V + _{} (1 − V) +  (6);
_{V}=0.973, _{}=0.996, C=0.005

> Con([NDVI-20200101 ]@1 <  0 , 0.991, Con(([NDVI-20200101 ]@1 >=0) AND ( [NDVI-20200101 ]@1 <0.2 )  ,0.996, Con( ( [NDVI-20200101 ]@1 >=0.2)  AND   ([NDVI-20200101 ]@1  <=  0.5),[Epsilon-20200101]@1 , Con([NDVI-20200101 ]@1 >0.5 , 0.973 ))))

But apparently it is not correct.